# Reactjs promises, how should we use it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I've been reading a lot about React for the last 3 days, but I don't see much information about the use of promises, so I have that concern.

Is there any library for this?

How should I use promises in React?

Comment: Maybe something is getting lost in translation, but _how should I use promises in React_ is impossibly broad; you should use them wherever you need to, with whichever library you prefer. I also did not interpret _is there any library for this_ to mean _does react provide this functionality_.

Comment: A multiplicity of approaches to async calls (promise, callback) can be used in react components. You use them in react the same way you would in other contexts. React specialises exclusively on the rendering. Look into Flux or similar frameworks for managing the data flow with react.

Comment: You might find information that might help you refine your question by googling `reactjs flux promise`: https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html, https://reactjsnews.com/getting-started-with-flux/, https://madebymany.com/blog/beyond-the-to-do-app-writing-complex-applications-using-flux-react-js. This will locate some libs as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-deferred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React doesn't come with a promise library baked in like Angular with `$http`.  You will have to find your own.

A few you can try:

- [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) (personal recommendation)
- jQuery's [`$ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
- Native promises (unless you actually have to support IE):  http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises

Comment: Why do you recommend Bluebird if I may ask? I kind-of feel that as a newbie in the Promise realm Bluebird is lacking in documentation..

Comment: I agree.  I've actually written an app in Redux recently and used Superagent  with that and found very little need for a Promise library.

Comment: No reactions.. Well I can recommend using https://github.com/github/fetch. Just `require('es6-promise').polyfill()` and `require('whatwg-fetch')` and it'll work. I include them in my entry point (main.js).

Comment: I would recommend axios

Answer (score 0):

Promise object is used for handling asynchronous computations which has some important guarantees that are difficult to handle with the callback method (the more old-school method of handling asynchronous code).

A Promise object is simply a wrapper around a value that may or may not be known when the object is instantiated and provides a method for handling the value after it is known (also known as resolved) or is unavailable for a failure reason (we'll refer to this as rejected).

Using a Promise object gives us the opportunity to associate functionality for an asynchronous operation's eventual success or failure (for whatever reason). It also allows us to treat these complex scenarios by using synchronous.

To see more at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-promise