# Best way to access API from React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

What's the best way for me to access an API using a React app? The API is currently developed in Golang using kami & mgo for the POST/GET/DELETE requests.

I want to be able to make a GET request to the following URL:

http://user:password@localhost:8000/api/v1/systems

on my React app and store the result in a state attribute:

```
this.state = {
    data: //store the data here
}
```

I also want to load this data whenever the page is loaded so maybe I should use the componentDidMount() function to handle this?

I've never used API calls on React, so I was wondering if anyone here could tell me a good way to this?

**EDIT**

I'm using React 15.3.2.

**EDIT #2**

I've taken a look at *fetch* to handle the requests, but I'm still unsure how to use it in my situation. I've got the react app running on localhost:3000 and the api running on localhost:8000, /api/v1/systems will return a JSON with the following format:

```
{ systems : [ //list of objects ] }
```

I've tried the following inside my componentDidMount():

```
fetch(myRequest) 
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    //this.setState({ data: result.json() });
    });
```

Not too sure what myRequest should be (been trying with a simple string of the URL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/systems') and I'm also not sure if the ports where the apps are running could make a conflict or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840412/reactjs-promises-how-should-we-use-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to decide on a library to do API calls. A simple way is to use `fetch`, which is built-in in modern browsers. There's a [polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) to cover older ones. [jQuery's AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [SuperAgent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent) are two alternatives. Here's a simple example using `fetch`. You'll only have to change the URL of the request.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: {} };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    fetch('http://reqres.in/api/users')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
      }).then(function(data) {
        self.setState({ data }, () => console.log(self.state));
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div/>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: I get the following errors when trying this: `localhost/:1 Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/v1/systems. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
`undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at TypeError (native)`

Comment: So the React code works and makes the GET request, but your server doesn't allow CORS. You need to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Here's [a pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12830156/6941627).